# Wordpress: Unique Custom Plugin CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to add custom CSS for several WordPress plugins I have in development. After some Googling around, I managed to find this bit of code:

```
function namespace_custom_style() {
    wp_register_style('namespace', plugins_url('namespace/style/style.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('namespace');
}
add_action('init', 'namespace_custom_style');
```

The issue with this, however, is that the styling made in this included file is used across the entire WordPress backoffice, whereas I would like unique styling per plugin. For example:

- For ***Plugin A*** I would like to have the meta-box be placed below the ***publish*** box, as it only has minor extra fields.
- For ***Plugin B*** this would not make sense, as this plugin allows users to select custom styling, such as the position of a child-element, colours, etc. As such, I would like to keep it below the MCE to make better use of the wider space.

I am aware that there exists an element with the ID ***[plugin_name]_meta*** that I can style to my hearts-content, so if the above is not an option I can do some hocus-pocus on that.

So in short: Is it possible to give simple WordPress plugins their own unique look-and-feel, and how?

If it's necessary for me to provide extra information, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Maybe.  "Plugin A" and "Plugin B" are specific plugins, authored by people who may have written them in very different ways.  We'd need to know _specifically_ which plugin (please ask only ONE at a time, per SO guidelines on [ask]), and _specifically_ where you want the styles applied (front end, back end, specific page / metabox, etc).  Details matter!

Comment: Also, if you _DO_ enqueue styles, please know two things: 1. Do it on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook (not the `init` hook), and 2. You can do the whole thing in `wp_enqueue_style(...)` (you don't need to register on one line, then enqueue on another.  [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) supports the same arguments as `wp_register_style`, and _also_ enqueues the style.

Comment: check this topic, hope it helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320928/wordpress-load-custom-css-for-specific-plugin-admin-page

Comment: @cale_b My apologies. I should have been specific that the styling should only be applied to the backoffice. Also, the plugins are not public yet, as they are still in development on my local machine, hence I could not provide the name of the plugins.

Comment: @AngelDeykov thank you! The code in that thread worked -I can't believe I never found that topic, even after x-hours of Googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks go out to Angel Deykov who pointed me to the right topic here on StackOverflow ([Wordpress: Load custom CSS for specific plugin admin Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320928/wordpress-load-custom-css-for-specific-plugin-admin-page))

I have updated my code like so:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'register_bonwaysbe_css_js');
function register_bonwaysbe_css_js($hook)
{
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    $screenId = $current_screen->id;

    if ($screenId !== 'bonway-static-block') {
        return;
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style('bonwaysbe_style', plugins_url('style/style.css',__FILE__ ));
    }
}
```

Granted, the example provided used ***strpos*** to compare the *ID* and *name*, but for some reason that always returned **false** for me, hence the ***!==***.